# Books On Compilation of C

Tags: c, books, assembly, binary-data

Are there any good books that explain:

1. C to Assembly code mapping for x86, for example how a while loop is constructed, how stack frames are constructed, etc.
2. The bit layout of datatypes in C (Integers and floats), how and why they are aligned with examples in assembly
3. The binary format and the process of assembling and linking (for UNIX operating systems), for example how symbol tables are used in linking and their memory structure.
4. How processors and RAM work, for example instruction scheduling, how data is retrieved from RAM.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Please note this site is about recommending *software,* not assets or [resources](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2470/185) like [howtos](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/882/185), [manuals/tutorials](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1258/185), [multi-media content](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/935/185), [code fragments](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/904/185), etc.

Comment: @Izzy Sorry, but is there some other comunity here for such questions?

Comment: Maybe, but I don't know, sorry.